# Add many Store Views: what is the impact on performance?

Tags: store-view, performance

Suppose I have a Magento installation organized like this:

```
-> `website` W
-->`store`   S
---> `store view` A
---> `store view` B
```

... and I decide to add 50 more `Store View` to the `Store` S

- How much this change is going to impact on the performance ?
- What I should take care of  ?

**UPDATE**
I'm trying to summarize all the shared points:

- More Product Flat tables -> re-index slower / more HD space
- Bigger Product Attribute tables -> some query slower / more HD space
- More cache records -> slower cache / more HD space
- possible impact on price index ( if websites number is increased too )

Answer (score 2):

As Amit already said, you have maybe to fight performance issues.

When we talked to Magentos Enterprise Consulting Group, they said, when we plan to create 20 or 30 or even more stores, we should think about faking this.

Like building a category or something alike.

I think the biggest problem is the price index, which is:

```
#customer group * #website * #tax classes * #products
```

See the website, not store view!

Comment: Sorry I don't go you: what you mean see `website, not store view` ?

Comment: The problem with the price index only is one, when you create a lot of websites for your store views.

Comment: so if I have one website/store with many storeview should be fine ?

Comment: In THIS regard - yes, but I'm sure you will have a lot of other problems :-)

Comment: yes that is what I said to my client when he told me he was going to buy 50 domains :)

Comment: Try and error. 50 storeviews might work, depending on many things, like catalog size, customer groups, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can create 50store. But it will create very bad effect on site  speeds.

Create issue In

- `Index management`
- `Mysql Query will increase .`